# .net Client Side Web app?

Tags: .net, x509certificate, keystore

Never done any .net stuff before and am wondering if it is possible to run a .Net web application client side through a browser? Or does it only work by processing on the server then spit out an HTML page? I would like to leverage the System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates namespace to access a user's Windows-MY keystore and pull out a X509 cert and its associated private key, which must be done client side, not server side for obvious reasons.

Comment: What does this even mean? Are you saying you want to build a .net web site and have people view it through a browser? Isn't that how every web application works?

Comment: @spinon - I think he's looking for Silverlight (which runs in the browser, not on the webserver) - but is there a legitimate reason to extract the private key? This seems nefarious...

Comment: Oh didn't think about. I would agree @John that it does sound a little suspicious to be pulling private keys.

Comment: I'm pulling the private key to decrypt data that was encrypted for the user using his public key. Our keys are protected by Entrust's ESP so the user will be prompted for his password before I will be able to access it. I was under the impression that .net works by processing on the server and spits out an HTML page to the client, no? I cant grab keys server side because they do not reside on the server, they reside on the user's computer hence my question. @John, does Silverlight offer Crypto capabilities?

Comment: It looks like Silverlight only offers basic symmetric encryption, no PKI support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up making a C# dll and registered it as a COM object, then interacted with it via JavaScript through the browser.